# MySQL Nested Queries with Joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following nested mysql synta which gives me an 1064 error code.

Below is the query.

```
SELECT m.member_id , m.username , m.email , g.permission 
FROM members m 
INNER JOIN members_groups q ON m.member_id = q.member_id 
INNERJOIN groups g on q.group_id = g.group_id 
WHERE username <> 'root' AND g.permission < 
(SELECT g.permission FROM members m 
INNER JOINmembers_groups q ON m.member_id = q.member_id 
INNER JOIN groups g on q.group_id = g.group_id WHERE m.member_id = 13)
```

The code involves three (3) tables.
 members table 
              |
              |
               members_groups table
              |
              |
  groups table

The members_groups tables contain the primary keys of members table and groups table as foreign keys.

Below is the error from the mysql console

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNERJOIN groups g on q.group_id = g.group_id WHERE username <> 'root' AND g.per' at line 1

Comment: There is a clue in the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need proper spaces around JOIN:

```
SELECT m.member_id , m.username , m.email , g.permission 
FROM members m INNER JOIN members_groups q ON m.member_id = q.member_id 
    INNER JOIN groups g on q.group_id = g.group_id 
WHERE username <> 'root' AND g.permission < 
    (SELECT g.permission 
    FROM members m INNER JOIN members_groups q ON m.member_id = q.member_id 
    INNER JOIN groups g on q.group_id = g.group_id WHERE m.member_id = 13)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many can be many reason for this error but in your case its typo.
Reference - http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/error-1064
 Check following image

[image]