# MySQL syntax issue on database and table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

What is wrong with my syntax?

I'm trying to update several databases in one shot:

```
update `db_name1`.`db_table` SET `cc_number_enc` = NULL
update `db_name2`.`db_table` SET `cc_number_enc` = NULL
update `db_name3`.`db_table` SET `cc_number_enc` = NULL
```

and I'm getting query syntax error in phpmyadmin

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '`cc_number_enc`Â =Â NULL' at line 1

**UPDATE**

I've rewritten the same query simply by copying & pasting, and now getting the following:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '`cc_number_enc` = NULL' at line 1

Question, is it matter from which database I'm running the query from in phpmyadmin?

Comment: query syntax where on which line?

Comment: post the error please?

Comment: could it be that you have "odd" whitespace there? Maybe re-type the query?

Comment: Looks like an odd character encoding issue. Try rewriting your query in plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

try puting semicolon after query. 
It can happen because of multiple reasons.
references http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/error-1064 
[MySQl Error #1064](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706498/mysql-error-1064)  
[MySQL Nested Queries with Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017886/mysql-nested-queries-with-joins/36018073#36018073)

Comment: tried to add semicolon, still getting the same error

Comment: add your table structure

Comment: is this field having any constraint like NOT NULL ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when copying, your backticks are changed to some other symbol, which looks like backtick, but actually, it is not.

Try again without quotes, or manually put backticks in place.